# Prevent duplicate data entered in list view

Tags: c#

How am i going to prevent duplicate data insert entered in list view, can anyone help for this, i am still new in C#

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
if (lvwRentBook.Items.Count == 0)
{
    lvi.Text = books.BookCode.ToString();
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.BookDesc.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.SupplierCode.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.PricePurchase.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(txtRentPRice.Text.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.PricePenalty.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add("1".ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.Author.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.Category.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.Active.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.ModifiedBy.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.ModifiedOn.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.CreatedBy.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(books.CreatedOn.ToString());
    lvwRentBook.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Comment: You are adding single item to empty list here. How you can get duplicated data in this case?

Comment: You cant get any duplicates here since you created a listview instance at the first part. is your book a list also ? please show the code.

Comment: what if i wan to validate duplicate data

Comment: use ListView.FindItemWithText() function to find if the item is already added. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3h4x385(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: does your book has a unique key/code/serial number? that prevents you getting duplicates.

Comment: i don't have unique key , if i entered two same data, it will shown twice in two row in the listbox, that is the problem i having now.i don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
 if(lvwRentBook != null)
 {
    ListViewItem lvi = lvwRentBook.FindItemWithText(books.BookCode.ToString());
    // if it is null means, item does not exist.You can go ahead and add it.
    if (lvi == null)
    {
     lvi = new ListViewItem();

        lvi.Text = books.BookCode.ToString();
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.BookDesc.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.SupplierCode.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.PricePurchase.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(txtRentPRice.Text.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.PricePenalty.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add("1".ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.Author.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.Category.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.Active.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.ModifiedBy.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.ModifiedOn.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.CreatedBy.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(books.CreatedOn.ToString());
        lvwRentBook.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other problems with the code but in terms of preventing duplicates consider using a HashSet. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your code here so I can't give you more help, but a HashSet will automatically prevent duplicate entries.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found was to enclose my whole ListView within an UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpSiteInvite" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="lsvSiteInvite" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" DataSourceID="srcSiteInvite"
            OnItemCommand="lsvSiteInvite_ItemCommand" runat="server">

...

        </asp:ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The only drawback is that this will repopulate the controls you used (textboxes, at least; not sure about DDLs). This wasn't a problem for me but if it is for you, I suppose it's possible to clear out the controls.